# T4 error when running Custom Tool in vs2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, t4

I do have an issue when I want to run the following command  "Run Cosutom Tool" from vs2017.

It stops working after a VS update.

Instead of running the T4 and generating all the code related to this file.
The output file will contains the following error message:

> Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Internal.OAFileItem'
>   in Assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package,
>   Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not marked as serializable.

Full error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Running transformation:
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Internal.OAFileItem' in
>   Assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package, Version=15.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as
>   serializable.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(MemberHolder
>   _)    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeMessageParts(ArrayList
>   argsToSerialize)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage..ctor(IMethodReturnMessage
>   mrm)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage.SmuggleIfPossible(IMessage
>   msg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[]
>   reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm,
>   SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[]
>   args)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at EnvDTE._Solution.FindProjectItem(String
>   FileName)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6FCAD03755FEA2CF76F69000C72CACC8E11DA21396664770DDB2AE835D7A8E82309989CCBC13688F6AC52D362D892E524A6D1554F901D313ED8AA1C0920ED56C.GeneratedTextTransformation.Manager.VSManager..ctor(ITextTemplatingEngineHost
>   host, StringBuilder template)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6FCAD03755FEA2CF76F69000C72CACC8E11DA21396664770DDB2AE835D7A8E82309989CCBC13688F6AC52D362D892E524A6D1554F901D313ED8AA1C0920ED56C.GeneratedTextTransformation.Manager.Create(ITextTemplatingEngineHost
>   host, StringBuilder template)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6FCAD03755FEA2CF76F69000C72CACC8E11DA21396664770DDB2AE835D7A8E82309989CCBC13688F6AC52D362D892E524A6D1554F901D313ED8AA1C0920ED56C.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() Staging D:\XXXXXXX\MedatadataGeneratedObjects.tt    1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my T4 I was using the `var dte = (DTE) hostServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));` I switched to use the `var dte = (DTE) hostServiceProvider.GetCOMService(typeof(DTE));`