# T4MVC throws a serialization error when trying to "Run Custom Tool"

Tags: c#, t4, visual-studio-2022, t4mvc

Today, after upgrading Visual Studio to 17.2.3 I get this error when trying to run T4MVC:

Running transformation: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase' in Assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.

I have seen others with the same issue, but the solutions suggested there do not solve it for me:
[VS2022 17.2.0 Preview 2.0: T4 template serialization exception when accessing projects, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575357/vs2022-17-2-0-preview-2-0-t4-template-serialization-exception-when-accessing-pr)
[T4 error when running Custom Tool in vs2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588524/t4-error-when-running-custom-tool-in-vs2017)

I have tried removing/adding the project, I've tried restarting Windows, I have no idea where to look as this was working without issues previously.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: After debugging more I can see that the inner exception is:
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsQueryEditQuerySave2'

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix the issue.

I ended up uninstalling VS (v. 17.2.3) and reinstalling and then repairing and after that (and applying the fixes already mentioned from this post: [VS2022 17.2.0 Preview 2.0: T4 template serialization exception when accessing projects, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575357/vs2022-17-2-0-preview-2-0-t4-template-serialization-exception-when-accessing-pr)) I am now able to run the T4MVC tool without errors.